# What is the regex for "2012-01-29 03:42:22"?

Tags: regex

I have tried this- [0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}) .... It gives me error

Comment: The regex looks basically correct, and I don't see any use of lookaheads or lookbehinds.  What error do you get, and what tool/language are you using?

Comment: Is the initial open bracket missing even in your code?

Comment: Add a `(` at the start: https://regex101.com/r/lF3nZ2/1

Answer (score 1):

You have an unbalanced paranthesis, otherwise this regex works fine.

A corrected solution would be: `([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})`

I'd suggest using a tool to validate your regex, like this one: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vB6uN4/1)

You might also want to check your **regex modifiers** or general quirks of the language you are using.

Comment: Glad to help! Would you mind marking the question as answered if it's correct for you? Would help me as a rather new SO member :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression to validate a date and time never ends well. There are too many edge cases: e.g. leap years, leap seconds (e.g. 2015-06-30 23:59:60) , oddities like September 1752 in England (no days in the range 3-13) etc.

The best thing to do is parse the string using your favourite date library and handle any error appropriately.

Comment: That regex isn't trying to validate, just match.

Comment: Can you please guide me in applying date library here for validation rather than using regexes